# titanium animate label color

Tags: animation, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Please see the following code snippet, tested in Appcelerator Studio SDK 5.2.0.GA:

```
//
// create base UI tab and root window
//
var win0 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Tab 1',
    backgroundColor:'#fff'
});

var label0 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    color:'red',
    text:'I am Window 1',
    font:{fontSize:20,fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'},
    textAlign:'center',
    width:'auto'
});

view0 = Titanium.UI.createView({
borderRadius:10
,width: 350
,height:40
,opacity:1
,color:"blue"
});

view0.add(label0);

win0.add(view0);

win0.open();

// Working
//win0.animate({backgroundColor:"blue", duration: 1000});

// Working
//view0.animate({backgroundColor:"blue", duration: 1000});

// Working
//label0.animate({backgroundColor:"blue", duration: 1000});

// "Working", but there is no duration (animation takes place right away)
label0.animate({color:"blue", duration: 1000});

// "Working", but there is no duration (animation takes place right away after the timer 5 sec timeout)
//setTimeout(function(){
//    label0.animate({color:"blue", duration: 1000});
//},5000);

// If win0.open is placed before the code below, there is no animation at all.
// If win0.open is placed after the code below, there is animation, but it takes place right away.
//win0.addEventListener('postlayout', function(e){
//  label0.animate({color:"blue", duration: 1000});
//});
```

The code creates a window with one view and one label inside view.

The 4 rows with animation are tested one at a time (i.e., to test, uncomment one at a time). The first one animates background color of window during 1 second. Works ok. The second one animates the background color of the view, works ok. The third one animates the background color of the label, works ok. And the fourth one is intended to animate the label text color. This does not work as one should expect. The animation takes place, but it takes place right away, not during 1 second.

Any idea on what could be wrong with code or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you don't see the animation because it's call just after opening the window. Try to add a setTimeout :

```
setTimeout(function(){
    label0.animate({color:"blue", duration: 1000});
},5000);
```

or, do your animation after the window postlayout event : https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-event-postlayout

```
win0.addEventListener('postlayout', function(e){
  label0.animate({color:"blue", duration: 1000});
});
```

Comment: I tried the two new code examples from the comment, but none of them gave the duration during the animation, it still took place right away... Isn't it a bit confusing if these examples should have worked, thinking of that animating the background color did work with animation duration?